# Run python script from Hue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hue

I'm using hive editor from hue.
I have table with IP column.
I have python script that get as parameter IP address and return IP location, I want to run the following command:

Select myscript(ipcolumn) as location from iptables where ipcolumn="1.1.1."

Is it possible to do something like that? To run python script from query and return new column from script and display it on table

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to pass all values of the IP column as a parameter to python script and execute it and getting IP values should be embedded in the Python/any script if I am correct.